# how to serialize two model in django rest framework to get nested json data

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Hi everyone i have two model one is Name and 2nd is Role, i have join two or more model multiple time, but this time response is different, here i have share my model and expected response,please help me out.

**models.py**

```
class Name(BaseModel):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    middle_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)

class Role(BaseModel):
    role=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    name=models.ForeignKey(Name, models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class RoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name=NameSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Role
        fields = "__all__"
```

**Current Response**

```
{
      "id": 1,
      "name": {
        "id": 1,     
        "first_name": "thor",
        "middle_name": "",
        "last_name": ""
        
      }
    }
```

**Expected Response**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "thor",
    "middle_name": "",
    "last_name": ""               
    "role": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": 1
                 }
 }
```

Comment: So what is an issue?  `RoleSerializer(your_role_instance)` should work fine

Comment: what response did you get??

Comment: @Xeus response is update on que.

Comment: @BartoszStasiak how can achive  expected response based on model

Answer (score 1):

you did the work upside down. you should use name serializer as parent and use that.

```
class RoleSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Role
        fields= "__all__"


class NameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    role=RoleSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Name
        fields = ['id','first_name','last_name','middle_name','role']
```

Comment: response in same not as i expected response

Comment: you have to pass NameSerializer to your View, not RoleSerializer , you didn't change the view i guess

Comment: yes thanks now getting proper response

Comment: @Xeue all record showing null except id

Comment: @KarishmaUpadhyay that came from the model double-check the field names dictation in fields

Comment: i have check field is correct but still giving null record all fields except id